# Заполнить форму по условию

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, как реализовать следующие:
при заполнении первого поля в форме во втором поле подставились автоматически данные в зависимости от первого. Допустим, выбираем  в первом поле сеть `192.168.1.1/24`, а во втором поле подставился свободный IP-адрес `192.168.1.111`.
Все это делается на Django.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите, чтобы это делалось мгновенно на странице, то только javascript. Вешаете обработчик на первое поле, как только его содержимое совпадает с нужным шаблоном заполняем второе поле необходимым текстом.

Я так понимаю, что свободный ip необходимо подобрать на основании данных о занятых ip в базе, в таком случае надо будет сделать AJAX-запрос к серверу. В django-коде нужно сделать представление, которое обработает поступившие данные (сеть 192.168.1.1/24) и выдаст нужный ip на основании логики работы вашего приложения. Это представление связывается с url в urlconf, на который вы и отправляете AJAX-запрос, например использовав средства [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: уже в этом направлении работаю, спасибо!