# Наследование в django

Tags: python, django

```
class SClients(models.Model):
    swname = models.ForeignKey(s_switch,verbose_name="SWITCH")
    vlan = models.ForeignKey(s_vlancl,verbose_name="VLAN")

class s_switch(models.Model):
    sw_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="SW_NAME",unique=True)
    vlan_cl = models.ManyToManyField(s_vlancl,verbose_name='VLAN_CL')
```

Как в admin-ке заполнить поле на основании выбранного значения, например: выбираем `swname` из таблицы `s_switch`, а поле `vlan` должно выбраться из заполненных данных `s_switch`(поле `vlan_cl`)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно при выборе из выпадающего списка swname динамически изменять значения для выбора в выпадающем списке vlan. В таком случае необходимо повесить в js-коде обработчик на список swname, когда в нем изменяется значение, нужно отправить ajax запрос на сервер, отфильтровать нужные данные из s_vlancl как-нибудь так:
`vlans = s_vlancl.objects.filter(s_switch=s_switch)`, вернуть их в js и сформировать на странице нужный выпадающий список. 
Посмотрите еще [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/42059/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#42106) вопрос.

Comment: Понятно, вообщем изучать js.

Comment: Вообще да, но с jQuery это все более-менее просто, и так как задача довольно типичная можно найти много примеров в интернете. На серверной стороне вам надо лишь написать представление, которое будет исходя из переданного параметра возвращать xml с нужными данными из базы. Дальше только добавить урл и обращаться на него из js-скрипта.

Answer (score -1):

Копай в сторону [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects)